# How to update entity desipite the row is loaded in EF change tracker or not in entity framework?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I allready look out everything of that problem but none of them worked for me.Everyone is suggestion to use `AsNoTracking()` for that problem but its has no sense with my problem because im not updating the data which i call from my database.

I have company profile update modal, this company can have profile photo or not but either way i need to update those informations. So that's why i need to control is comapny creating a photo or updating a photo. Let me show u to my code in the bellow :

```
#region /*UpdateCompanyProfile*/
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UpdateCompanyProfile(Company company, List<IFormFile> files, int FileID)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            company.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
            _unitOfWorkC.RepositoryCompany.Update(company);
            int firstRequest = HttpContext.Response.StatusCode;
            if (firstRequest == 200)
            {
                _unitOfWorkC.Complete();
                if (files.Count != 0)
                {
                    var File = _fileUploader.FileUploadToDatabase(files);
                    var FileResult = File.Result;
                    FileResult.CompanyID = company.CompanyID;
                    if (FileID == 0)//That's the point where i control that file, is it gonna be update or create.
                    {
                        _unitOfWorkFR.RepositoryFileRepo.Create(FileResult);
                        int secondRequest1 = HttpContext.Response.StatusCode;
                        if (secondRequest1 == 200)
                        {
                            int tryCatch = _unitOfWorkFR.Complete();
                            if (tryCatch != 15)
                            {
                                TempData["JS"] = "showSuccess();";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                TempData["JS"] = "showError();";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        FileResult.FileID = FileID;
                        _unitOfWorkFR.RepositoryFileRepo.Update(FileResult); //That's the point where i get the error.
                        int secondRequest2 = HttpContext.Response.StatusCode;
                        if (secondRequest2 == 200)
                        {
                            int tryCatch2 = _unitOfWorkFR.Complete();
                            if (tryCatch2 != 15)
                            {
                                TempData["JS"] = "showSuccess();";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                TempData["JS"] = "showError();";
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            TempData["JS"] = "showError();";
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["Message"] = "?irket g?ncelleme i?leminiz ba?ar?s?z!";
                TempData["JS"] = "showError();";
                return RedirectToAction("CompanyProfile");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["Message"] = "G??ncellemek istedi?iniz veri hatal?!";
            TempData["JS"] = "showError();";
            return RedirectToAction("CompanyProfile");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var log = _logging.Logging(ex.Message, "Exception/Hata", company.CompanyID.ToString(),
            "CompanyProfile/UpdateCompanyProfile", getCurrentUser(), getCurrentUserClaimRole());
        _unitOfWorkLog.RepositoryLog.Create(log);
        _unitOfWorkLog.Complete();
        //TempData["Message"] = ex.Message;
        //TempData["JS"] = "showError();";
        return RedirectToAction("CompanyProfile");
    }
}
#endregion
```

As u can see, calling that data with `AsNoTracking()` has no sense in my stuation. I'm only getting that error in that action,so other `FileRepo` actions are working well.

That's my `FileUploadToDatabase()` method :

```
        public async Task<FileRepo> FileUploadToDatabase(List<IFormFile> files)
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName);
                var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                _fileRepo = new FileRepo
                {
                    FileName = fileName,
                    FileExtension = fileExtension,
                    FileType = file.ContentType,
                    CreatedDate= DateTime.Now
                };
                using (var dataStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(dataStream);
                    _fileRepo.FileData = dataStream.ToArray();
                }
            }
            return _fileRepo;
        }
```

And that's my `FileRepo` class :

```
   public class FileRepo : Base
    {
        [Key]
        public int FileID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Field !")]
        public string FileName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Field !")]
        public string FileType { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Field !")]
        public string FileExtension { get; set; }

        public string FilePath { get; set; }
        public bool FilePhotoIsDefault { get; set; }
        public byte[] FileData { get; set; }
        public int? CompanyID { get; set; }
        public Company Company { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }
```

That's my UnitOfWork :

[image]

and This is my Repository :

[image]

[image]

This is the query for my Update Modal:

```
        public IEnumerable<Company> GetByIDForCompanyProfileCompany(int ID)
        {
            return TradeTurkDBContext.Companies.Where(x => x.CompanyID == ID)
               .Include(x => x.Addresses.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == null || x.IsDeleted == false))
               //
               .Include(x => x.Products.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == null || x.IsDeleted == false))
               .ThenInclude(x => x.FileRepos.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == null || x.IsDeleted == false)).AsSplitQuery()
               //
               .AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution().ToList();
        }
```

Comment: Problem hidden in boilerplate `UnitOfWork` realization. To update record you just need to change property of tracked object, then `SaveChanges`. That's all.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv can you be more spesific because i could not understand. I changed some values of that property like ModifiedDate or etc. its still giving me that error

Comment: Better to show your UnitOfWork and Repository implementation.

Comment: Anyway looks like I see your problem.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv i have updated my question for you.

Comment: Anyway, `AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution` is your problem. It means that ChangeTracker remembers loaded objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For updating FileResult you are using DbSet.Update - it is trying to attach entity to ChangeTracker. Attaching will fail if there is already attached object with the same key.

Change your repository to the following. It will update all fields if entity is not in `ChangeTracker`, otherwise it will correct only needed properties:

```cs
public void Update(T model)
{
    if (model == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(model));

    // I hope your generic repository knows Model Id property
    var entry = _context.ChangeTracker.Entries<T>().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Entity.Id == model.Id);

    if (entry == null)
    {
        // entity not tracked, so attach it
        _dbSet.Update(model);
    }
    else
    {
        // setting values from not tracked object
        if (!ReferenceEquals(model, entry.Entity))
            entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(model);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

If generic repository don't know about `Id` property, you can define interface for that:

```cs
public interface IEntityWithId 
{ 
   int Id {get;}
}
```

Make sure that your classes is implementation of `IEntityWithId`. Then correct Repository definition:

```cs
public interface IRepository<T> where T: class, IEntityWithId
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: my generic repository dont know Model Id property. Thank you for your answer but, can u give me some hints about that ? some sources so i can look around for it.

Comment: Updated answer.