# EF core: Update specific fields got tracking error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am working on updating specific field of entity in EF core 3.

The scenario is:

I have a blog entity

```
class Blog
{
  Public int Id{get;set;}
  Public int Title {get;set;}
  Public int Content{get;set;}
}
```

First I query the blog (id=1) with tracking

Second I query the blog (id=1) without tracking. Then I update the title on this instance and want to save only field Title
I created a method to do update individual fields:

```
   public void UpdateIndividualField<T>(T entity, Func<T, bool> identitySearchQuery, params 
      Expression<Func<T, object>>[] properties) where T : class
    {
        Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry<T> entry = 
       this.Entry(entity);

        if (!this.Set<T>().Local.Any(identitySearchQuery))
        {
            this.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
        }

        foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> property in properties)
        {
            entry.Property(property).IsModified = true;
        }
    }
```

but when I update the title on second instance, I got an error message saying:

**The instance of entity type 'Blog' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value...**

It works on EF core 2.2 but not for EF core 3

Does anyone khow why? and how to fix for EF core 3.

Comment: Probably you will find this answer useful. I have not found better way (except getting PK via reflection) https://stackoverflow.com/a/68273563/10646316

Comment: Thanks @SvyatoslavDanyliv. Works fine for me.