# Entity Framework Core adds to ChangeTracker the ApplicationUser who is sending the request in a Api with Local Authentication

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, identityserver4

my API has LocalApiAuthentication, Identity Server is integrated inside the API.
I have these classes in my API:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid> {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public virtual Business Business {get; set;}
}

public class Business {
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public virtual List<ApplicationUser> Users {get; set;}
}
```

Then, when I try to update my **Business** name sending the request with my **User** from a web, automatically the ChangeTracker adds my User and the Business to the ChangeTracker and then the API send this error in response =>

`System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'ApplicationUser' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.`

Do you have the solution for this?

Comment: This week, you are third with this question. Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68273563/10646316

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Thanks you but it is not exactly my problem

Comment: It's your problem. Change Tracker already contains object with the same key. And you are trying to attach another.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Yeah, of course, but in this case I'm not updating my **User**, I'm updating my **Business**