# How update a row in desepite it is tracked or not in efcore?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I have a repository that uses the EfCore as ORM. I want to update a row that was recently inserted inside de database. but I am getting this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'NewsLetter' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked.

I examine all of these codes but had no success.

1.

```
_context.Remove(entity);
_context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

2. _context.Attach(entity);
   _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
   await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
3. 

```
_context.Update(entity);
_context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

4. 

```
_context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

5. 

```
_context.Update(entity)
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

6. _context.Set.Update(entity)
   await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The instance of entity type 'FileRepo' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'FileID'} is already being tracked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68271940/the-instance-of-entity-type-filerepo-cannot-be-tracked-because-another-instanc)

Comment: It works thank but I think the title of that question is not search friendly and it may not find in regular searchs

Comment: I can answer here again ;)