# How to design repository based on Entity Framework core?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have created a Repository on top of Entity Framework Core, but have some issues with how it's done.

This is an example:

```
    public class StockPricesRepository : IStockPricesRepository
    {

        StockPricesDbContext _stockPricesDbContext;
        ILogger _logger;

        public StockPricesRepository(StockPricesDbContext stockPricesDbContext, ILogger logger)
        {
            _stockPricesDbContext = stockPricesDbContext;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void Add(StockPrice stockPrice)
        {
            _stockPricesDbContext.Add(stockPrice);
            _stockPricesDbContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void AddOrUpdate(StockPrice stockPrice)
        {
            if (!Exists(stockPrice))
                _stockPricesDbContext.Add(stockPrice);
            else
                _stockPricesDbContext.Update(stockPrice);
            _stockPricesDbContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        private bool Exists(StockPrice stockPrice)
        {
            StockPrice existingStockPrice = Get(stockPrice.Ticker, stockPrice.Exchange, stockPrice.Date, stockPrice.DataProvider);

            return (existingStockPrice != null);
        }

        public StockPrice Get(string ticker, string exchange, DateTime date, string providerName)
        {
            StockPrice stockPrice = null;

            stockPrice =
                (from sp in _stockPricesDbContext.StockPrices
                        where (
                        (sp.Ticker == ticker) &
                        (sp.Exchange == exchange) &
                        (sp.Date == date) &
                        (sp.DataProvider == providerName))
                    select sp).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();

            return stockPrice;
        }

    }
}
```

The StockPricesDbContext is injected into the constructur using dependency injection like this:

```
services.AddDbContext<StockPricesDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

The problem with the current design is that I get some issues with multiple calls into the repository within the lifetime of the StockPricesDbContext object (even if I have AsNoTracking() on the Get method):

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'StockPrice' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Date', 'Ticker', 'Exchange', 'DataProvider'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.'
```

To avoid this problem I would maybe prefer to have each of the repository methods embedded in a using block like this:

```
using (var db = new StockPricesDbContext())
{
}
```

The problem with this approach is that I don't get the StockPricesDbContext from dependency injection and the connection string from AddDbContext is lost.

One workaround for that might be to get the connection string from the constructor of the repository like this:

```
private string _connectionString;

public StockPricesRepository(StockPricesDbContext stockPricesDbContext, ILogger logger)
{
    _stockPricesDbContext = stockPricesDbContext;
    _connectionString = stockPricesDbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString;
    _logger = logger;
}
```

I would also need to add this constructor in StockPricesDbContext:

```
public StockPricesDbContext(string connectionString)
{
    _connectionString = connectionString;
}
```

and this would be the OnConfiguring method:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        if (_connectionString != null)
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_connectionString);
    }
}
```

Then I could use it in the methods like this:

```
using (var db = new StockPricesDbContext(_connectionString))
{
}
```

It kind of works, but seems a bit "unclean".

Has anyone else come across a good pattern for repositories built on top of Entity Framework Core?

Comment: the issue might be `_stockPricesDbContext.SaveChanges();` call in each repository method. This is not the usual approach you should save changes only once after Updating data. Create a method save changes in repository and call it after performing your functions. Issue might be context try to save another change while an existing instance is saving

Comment: The issue in my simple case is reproduced by call the AddOrUpdate method twice. I could of course split out Save as it's own method and that would most likely also result in better performance, since I could add / update multiple items and then do the save. Is it common for repositories to have a separate "Save" method instead of the usual CRUD operations?

Comment: I tried to split out the SaveChanges in a separate method and I still got the error after calling my AddOrUpdate method twice (with no SaveChanges), so I don't think that will help.

Comment: Check this [Update method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68273563/10646316). It shows how to update detached entity correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The common mistake that causes this error is having several async queries that have not been committed.

There is no problem saving multiple records in EF though.

There are multiple approaches to avoid your issue.

**Using AddRange(),UpdateRange(),DeleteRange()**

`AddRange()` can add list of objects to your db and you don't need to call `.Add()` more than once. Similarly you can update or delete a list of objects

**EFCore.BulkExtensions**

[Bulk Extensions in EFCore](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions)

Both are extending DbContext with Bulk operations and have the same syntax call:

```
context.BulkInsert(stockPriceList);
context.BulkUpdate(stockPriceList);
context.BulkDelete(stockPriceList);
context.BulkInsertOrUpdate(stockPriceList);
```

Comment: Yes, I could use methods taking lists of object. But, I don't think it would fundamentally solve my issue, since a operations for adding a list could also be called multiple times and maybe cause similar errors. I'm more interested in solving the design issue of the repository than being concerned about performance right now.

Comment: using AddRange WILL solve your design issue of calling Add again and again. Moreover as I told you repository pattern has it's own method for save changes just as Add. these are the possible fixes for your problem of using multiple instances at the same time.

Comment: Why doesn't SaveChanges cancel the change tracking to start from fresh again? Maybe a fix would also to manually cancel all change tracking after a SaveChanges operation?

Comment: you can try `context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;` to stop context from detecting instances